# Compare two lists in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the data set(image) returned from this query:

```
MATCH(node:CXEligibilityRuleConstruct)-[:_properties]->(a)-->(spoke) with node
MATCH(node)<-[r:CXEHasChild]-(parent) where parent.nodeName='Network Segmentation' with node
Match(node)-[r:CXComponentHasCXRuleConstruct]-(cxc:CXComponentHierarchy{_type:'CXComponent'})
return node.elementLabel, collect( distinct  cxc.elementLabel)
```

[image: DATA SET]

Now if the user inputs a list, eg: `['Catalyst 9300','Cisco DNA Center','DNA Premier', 'ISE Appliance']`, how do I return the `node.elementLabel` related to that match?

Comment: What do you mean by "related to that match"? Do the lists have to be identical (i.e., have the same items, regardless of the order), or can a match have extra items not in the user's list, or can a match have any items in the user's list, or ...?

Comment: yeah they have to be same as in same elements regardless of the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the user's list is passed as a `list` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/), and you want to match `cxc.elementLabel` lists exactly (except for element order), this should work:

```
MATCH (node:CXEligibilityRuleConstruct)-[:_properties]->()-->()
MATCH (node)<-[:CXEHasChild]-(parent)
WHERE parent.nodeName = 'Network Segmentation'
WITH node
MATCH (node)-[:CXComponentHasCXRuleConstruct]-(cxc:CXComponentHierarchy)
WHERE cxc._type = 'CXComponent' AND apoc.coll.disjunction(cxc.elementLabel, $list) = []
RETURN node.elementLabel
```

The APOC function `apoc.coll.disjunction(a, b)` returns a list with the elements that are not in both `a` and `b`.

[UPDATE]

If you can't use APOC, and `$list` never has any duplicate elements, then this should work:

```
MATCH (node:CXEligibilityRuleConstruct)-[:_properties]->()-->()
MATCH (node)<-[:CXEHasChild]-(parent)
WHERE parent.nodeName = 'Network Segmentation'
WITH node
MATCH (node)-[:CXComponentHasCXRuleConstruct]-(cxc:CXComponentHierarchy)
WHERE cxc._type = 'CXComponent' AND
  SIZE(cxc.elementLabel) = SIZE($list) AND
  ALL(x IN $list WHERE x IN cxc.elementLabel)
RETURN node.elementLabel
```